# How to import existing database from SQL Server into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there any software that I can use to do this, or do I need to create a dump file from SQL Server that is compatible with MySQL?

Comment: mssql can export dbs as .sql dumps, but it's not likely to import into mysql cleanly,e specially if you're using any mssql sql-extensions/features.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the MySQL ODBC driver installed you can do the transfer with SQL Server management Studio (or whatever they're calling it now).

It doesn't do a great job with metadata so you'll probably have to deal with the constraints manually, as well as tweak the column definitions, but it will transfer the data.